# Sitecore insert options rules

Tags: templates, insert, sitecore, rule-engine

I have a scenario where I would like to add insert options based on roles. So imagine I have a folder in the content tree called 'Components'.

I have two roles called 
 - Contributors 
 - Approvers

I have 3 templates which I want to pick and choose from to show as Insert Options on the 'Components' folder.
 - Template 1
 - Template 2
 - Template 3

For Contributors, I only want to show Template 1 as the Insert Option.

For Approvers, I only want to show Template 2 and Template 3 as the Insert Options.

How can I achieve this?

I thought about this scenario. Apply all Templates as Insert Options to the Components folder and then remove templates based on roles using /sitecore/system/Settings/Rules/Insert Options rules but it is not working.

I am using Sitecore 8 update 2.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't use `Insert Options` at all.

Just create a new rule under `/sitecore/system/Settings/Rules/Insert Options rules` and create 2 rules:

1. `when user is in role and item is Components - add this and that insert option`
2. `when user is in another role and item is Components - add that and another insert option`

I've written a blog post about `Insert Options Rules` - maybe it will help you. You can find it here: [Sitecore Insert Options Rules](http://www.skillcore.net/sitecore/sitecore-insert-options-rules)

Comment: That is what I was looking for. Thanks!